# Sort array of numbers in Scientific Notation

Tags: ruby, sorting, scientific-notation

I would like to sort an array of numbers (in scientific notation) from the smallest to the highest.

This is what I have tried (in vain):

```
require 'bigdecimal'
s = ['1.8e-101','1.3e-116', '0', '1.5e-5']
s.sort { |n| BigDecimal.new(n) }.reverse

# Results Obtained
# => [ "1.3e-116", "1.8e-101", "0", "1.5e-5" ]

# Expected Results
# => [ "0", "1.3e-116", "1.8e-101", "1.5e-5"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The block of `Enumerable#sort` is expected to return `-1`, `0` or `1`. What you want is [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
s.sort_by { |n| BigDecimal.new(n) }
# => ["0", "1.3e-116", "1.8e-101", "1.5e-5"]
```

Comment: Nice article to explain more. http://brandon.dimcheff.com/2009/11/18/rubys-sort-vs-sort-by.html

Comment: Or `s.sort_by(&BigDecimal.method(:new))` if you are into point-free style.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`BigDecimal#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) within `sort`:

```
s.sort { |x, y| BigDecimal(x) <=> BigDecimal(y) }
#=> ["0", "1.3e-116", "1.8e-101", "1.5e-5"]
```